# Where does jqgrid 'restoreRow' store its data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I used jqgrid inline-edit feature in my project, when I was editing a row, I don't want to save it later, it will restore the former data, I was wondering where jqgrid stored its former data, what method can I use to get its former data when I was editing a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, per the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) you can use the grid parameter `savedRow`:

> This is a readonly property and is used in inline and cell editing modules to store the data, before editing the row or cell.

As @Arnav wrote, you can easily access this `savedRow` parameter using `getGridParam`:

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
```

---

In case you are interested, internally there is an array `$t.p.savedRow` that the previous data is stored to. You can see this within the `restoreRow` function in [`grid.inlineedit.js`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js):

```
for( var k=0;k<$t.p.savedRow.length;k++) {
    if( $t.p.savedRow[k].id == rowid) {fr = k; break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid saves the data into option `savedRow` before entering into editing mode. And there is a library method provided to access that data:

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
```